# htaccess issue when moving site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that I have moved to a testing area on a different server. The URL is:

http://www.example.co.uk/clientarea/royston/the_team (This isn't a live site so the link won't actually work)

When the site was on the live server it would have been:

http://www.example.co.uk/the_team

I have a htaccess file that looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

##Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

##Ignore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/internal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/modules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts

##Remove .php from filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

I need to know how to change the htaccess so that the URL will work on the test site.

Many thanks

Comment: There is no need to change the above file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change theses lines :

```
RewriteBase /clientarea/royston/
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /clientarea/royston/$1.php [L]
```

**EDIT :** You could also use your ReweireRule like this so you wont need to change it

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Using rewrite rules without a starting slash make this kind of changes easier : `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]`. Then, only the `RewriteBase` needs to be changed.